# Difference between Expectation and matchers in Rspec

Tags: rspec, rspec2

Hi all I am new to rspec, can anyone tell me like what is the difference between 
expectations and matchers its quite confusing me.

i have gone through some examples but unable to understand can anyone help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These concepts are explained quite well in the docs:

[RSpec Expectations](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs)

[RSpec Built-in Matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers)

If you are familiar with other test frameworks, expectations work like assertions. Matchers are used within expectations to get the value(s) to be tested.

Comment: @farooq Did you follow either of the links? I'm not trying to nag, I'm honestly curious as to whether you felt the examples in the docs were lacking and whether it's worth it to create a substantive SO post.